# How to change multiple Boolean values()Parent Item, Child Item) in an array on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am working in a task where I need to change the Boolean values onclick from an array of items, I need to change the Boolean value from array and child array. I have changed the value from an array it's working as expected but inside that array I am having an another array of objects from that I need to change the boolean value. OnClick I need to make parent isProcessing and child isProcessing false. I have tried changing it but I am not getting the expected output , can  anyone guide me how to achieve this thanks in advance.

Mock Data:

```
const mockItems = [
  {
    id: '1',
    itemType: 'metal',
    doneBy: {
      id: '1',
      display: 'Item Name',
    },
    catg: 'A',
    createdDate: '01/01/2021',
    updatedBy: {
      id: '1',
      type: 'M-A',
    },
    isProcessing: 'true',
    subItems: [
      {
        id: '1',
        doneBy: {
          id: '1',
          display: 'sub item name',
        },
        status: {
          type: 'notapproved',
        },
        isProcessing: 'true',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Code for accessing parent : isProcessing //it's working

```
const [processingItem, setProcessingItem] = useState(mockItems);

const handleToggle = () => {
  setProcessingItem((prevState) =>
    prevState.map((prItem, i) =>
      i === 0 ? { ...prItem, isProcessing: false } : prItem
    )
  );
};

//code to change child array Boolean not working

const handleToggle = () => {
  setProcessingItem((prevState) => {
    prevState.map((prItem, index) => {
      if (index === 0) {
        const obj = { ...prItem.subItems, isProcessing: false };
        return { ...prItem, isProcessing: false, obj };
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-mclean-9m4oeo

Comment: Do you just need to set all `isProcessing` to `false` when you click?  Right now you have a text representation of a boolean value of "true" or "false" stored in the object.
Perhaps you need to parse the value and invert it?

Comment: @A1exandrBelan I need to set isProcessing to false for the first item in the parent and for the first item in the child array.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan na, it's not working for me :(

Comment: @Still_Learning, Check this updated sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-beaver-55ghis

Comment: @ManirajMurugan, I can see the difference in setting state can you please explain the reason for it ?

Comment: @Still_Learning, I have considered the action happen's once, so directly included `processingItem` and included the `map` method to it.  But  If there will be constant update in the state variable and if you need to have the `prevState` reference then you can handle that as well. I have updated sandbox again here https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-cherry-vjmyoh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
const handleToggle = () => {
        setProcessingItem((prevState) => {
            prevState.map((prItem, index) => {
                if(index !=0)
                return prItem;
                const subItems = prItem.subItems.map((si,idx)=>{
                    return idx != 0 ? si : {...si,isProcessing: false}
                });
                return { ...prItem, isProcessing: false, subItems:subItems }
            }
            )
        }
        )
    }
```

Comment: I have to change the first element for that I have used index , but that is not working for me any idea how to use index for both subItems and prItem

Comment: @Still_Learning see update ans it will changes the first element of item and subitem